# Exception when running model:all() but not when seeding my DB - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

PHP 8.2.5

Laravel 10.8.0

10.11.2-MariaDB

openSuse Tumbleweed

---

I am trying to learn php/laravel by making a simple mvc web app based on a tutorial I found online. I already am versed in Python and Java and have made web apps before. However, I'm having a weird issue when I try to access the data on the DB to display in a view. I get this message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from listings`)`

The thing is, that my migration is working and the seeding is working too. Which leads me to believe that it isn't related to my connection infos and everything I see about this problem is mostly related to those. I tried the UNIX socket switch I saw in another post and it didn't help either. I cleared all my db and ran all the migrations fresh in my docker but it didn't solve anything. What other reasons would there be for that Exception? I'm really banging my head about this one.

---

**[EDIT]**: I have tried the fixes suggested by @Coola and I was in fact migrating to my local mysql instead of the docker instance but now I have the same error but when migrating.

```bash
user@localhost:~/xxxxx/example-app> sail artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

---

Files I think are relevant:

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=example_app
DB_USERNAME=example_user
DB_PASSWORD=example_password
```

database.php

```php
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3307'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'example_app'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => '/run/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```php
mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3307'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '${DB_HOST}'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
```

Listing.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Listing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

web.php

```php
<?php

use App\Models\Listing;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
    return view('listings', [
        'heading' => 'Test Listing',
        'listings' => Listing::all()
    ]);
});
```

listings_table_migration.php

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('listings');
    }
};
```

Results of querying directly in mysql

```sql
LaZoR_Bear@localhost:~/Decizif/example-app> mysql -u example_user -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 8
Server version: 10.11.2-MariaDB MariaDB package

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> use example_app
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [example_app]> SHOW TABLES;
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_example_app  |
+------------------------+
| failed_jobs            |
| listings               |
| migrations             |
| password_reset_tokens  |
| personal_access_tokens |
| users                  |
+------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [example_app]> SELECT * FROM listings;
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title                                                    | description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Quasi officia voluptatem ut consequatur voluptatibus.    | Consequuntur repudiandae omnis molestiae numquam qui. Dolor hic voluptas dicta deleniti. Qui sed odit adipisci asperiores dignissimos quas. Ut provident ut nam et. Quia tenetur et omnis enim sint ut. Vitae voluptatem alias dignissimos distinctio deleniti ea molestias. Eum dolorem et modi aspernatur qui occaecati quia.                                                                                                                                                         | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
|  2 | Aut est aliquid labore.                                  | Dolorem ex doloremque sed praesentium sit ut similique sit. Minus maiores dolorem voluptates fugit nobis et. Qui facere temporibus ad ex omnis. Inventore et ipsam quos qui veritatis repellat. Atque eaque voluptates quia. Quia commodi perferendis minima consectetur consequuntur eligendi dolores.                                                                                                                                                                                 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
|  3 | Minima cum provident voluptatem possimus.                | Perferendis odit exercitationem ipsum. Earum quia nam sed accusantium. Ab fugiat ut odio quaerat. Iure laboriosam aut aut totam iste ut incidunt. Ut ducimus quo ab omnis ex. Autem quia delectus molestiae explicabo iure. Itaque molestiae tenetur ipsa vel. Consectetur modi neque suscipit quod id dicta libero. Facilis molestiae voluptatem ullam officia vel et aut. Necessitatibus eum cumque voluptas dolor eveniet magnam. Veniam ab iste excepturi laudantium autem nostrum. | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
|  4 | Sit possimus atque delectus minima.                      | Quo quis qui odit eveniet tenetur beatae. Eum ut omnis aut ipsam amet officiis. Et sed non repudiandae eos rerum. Aut qui non et dignissimos vel nihil numquam. Asperiores adipisci illum accusamus molestiae vero dolores nostrum. Hic numquam autem molestias aut voluptates molestiae possimus laborum.                                                                                                                                                                              | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
|  5 | Dicta natus quam officia rerum perspiciatis repellendus. | Deserunt et libero odit a aut voluptatibus. Sunt laboriosam sequi ut id nihil quia. Recusandae laboriosam ea amet dolores. Assumenda mollitia soluta nam enim eum vel. Qui voluptatum praesentium nihil exercitationem enim. Consequatur dicta corporis dolorem nisi magnam tempore. Et laborum vel veniam omnis praesentium est rerum. Fugit dolorem sed ut repudiandae consequatur. Sit deserunt ullam numquam aperiam corporis at rem impedit.                                       | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
|  6 | Rerum velit animi vel maxime.                            | Ut ipsam ipsum quaerat vel. Nostrum ea beatae vel quia voluptatum ut perferendis iusto. Excepturi dolorum reprehenderit quis provident. Necessitatibus perferendis numquam dolorem laborum ea vero. Veritatis et non nihil et quo. Magnam iste fugiat odit qui facilis iste sit. In id modi vitae sunt iusto. Esse distinctio corporis nihil adipisci dignissimos voluptas.                                                                                                             | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
|  7 | Odio sint amet illum.                                    | Suscipit dolor molestiae sapiente earum reiciendis aliquam quae. Dignissimos ad iste voluptatem voluptas perferendis molestiae. Consectetur rerum qui possimus. Saepe est quidem sed harum. Sit quos et quos deleniti autem voluptate. Voluptatem nesciunt at voluptas iusto et dolorum. Fugit odit quo eius rerum. Magni sint nisi laboriosam architecto. Est quia ullam voluptate quae. Enim reprehenderit qui quam ut omnis voluptas sed.                                            | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
|  8 | Ex sit reiciendis sed est nihil.                         | Omnis minus reprehenderit in et rerum ut. Ut quisquam iste deserunt vel. Quis ut consequuntur autem labore blanditiis perferendis et. Natus quo reiciendis expedita id. Quas non esse minus quam ea repellendus. Eum saepe officia voluptatem quod similique eaque voluptates. Laborum nesciunt doloremque qui. Rerum voluptatem modi et rerum et laudantium quo.                                                                                                                       | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
|  9 | Sed dicta sit error cumque.                              | Dolore sed non in magnam assumenda nam nam. In est aliquid rerum. Aspernatur dolores et exercitationem vitae. Corrupti ut officia commodi veritatis qui. Qui eaque neque sint a. Ea deserunt dolor cum ratione numquam aliquam. Est hic dolore ea velit et. Impedit fuga expedita repudiandae ad. Consequatur modi et maiores deserunt ipsa ut ab.                                                                                                                                      | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
| 10 | Est suscipit blanditiis eum aut minima dolor.            | Voluptate labore rerum hic et voluptatibus qui fugiat et. Est veritatis nihil harum amet praesentium. Qui ducimus repellendus voluptatem in. Fugiat eum ratione nulla reiciendis enim in. Veritatis voluptatem cupiditate quibusdam facilis. Placeat molestiae fugit temporibus unde. Magnam dicta ipsum error autem voluptatem et distinctio.                                                                                                                                          | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 | 2023-04-25 14:11:31 |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Are you using sail? If so you need to run the migrations in the docker instance of the mysql database and not your mariaDB instance.

Comment: Not expert here, but, If your DB is in a docker instance, how can it be IP 127.0.0.1 which I woudl expect to be the host machine?

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right, I have updated the post after I changed the .env to reflect the correct settings for my container.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be happening currently is you are migrating the data to the MariaDB instance and not to the docker MySQL instance.

Assuming you have Laravel Sail installed and are running using Sail. Setup the [Sail alias](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#configuring-a-shell-alias) and then you can run the migration using Sail like so:

```
sail artisan migrate
```

Comment: I followed your steps and updated my post with an edit since I'm getting the same error but at a different place. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try running `sail artisan config:clear` and `sail artisan optimize:clear` also `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan optimize:clear`. Maybe your settings/env was cached and it is not updating the settings. Also did you do the `sail up` command to get your docker images up?